# Remove generic type arguments from class signature

Tags: c#, .net, expression

I wrote a simple object to object mapper, which is mainly used to map EF models to DTOs. The individual maps are expressions in the form:

```
public static Expression<Func<Model.Product, Dto.Product>> ProductMap = source =>
    new Dto.Product
    {
        ProductId = source.Id,
        ProductName = source.Name
    };
```

When mapping the expressions to a single instantiated object, I call .Compile() on the expression to get a delegate and then pass in the source object to get a destination object.

```
public static class MapBuilder
{
    public static TDest ToInstance<TSource, TDest>(TSource source, Expression<Func<TSource, TDest>> map)
    {
        return map.Compile()(source);
    }
}

// Use:
var source = _context.Product.Find(productId);
MapBuilder.ToInstance(source, Maps.Product);
```

This works, but I want to cache the expression compilation. Here's what was done for that.

```
public static class ExpressionCache<TSource, TDest>
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<(Type, Type), Func<TSource, TDest>> _mapCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<(Type, Type), Func<TSource, TDest>>();

    public static Func<TSource, TDest> Compile(Expression<Func<TSource, TDest>> map)
    {
        Func<TSource, TDest> cachedFunc;

        ValueTuple<Type, Type> t = (typeof(TSource), typeof(TDest));

        if (!_mapCache.TryGetValue((typeof(TSource),typeof(TDest)), out cachedFunc))
        {
            cachedFunc = map.Compile();
            _mapCache[t] = cachedFunc;
        }

        return cachedFunc;
    }
}
```

And the corresponding change to MapBuilder:

```
public static TDest ToInstance<TSource, TDest>(TSource source, Expression<Func<TSource, TDest>> map)
{
    //return map.Compile()(source);
    return ExpressionCache<TSource, TDest>.Compile(map)(source);
}
```

With all that in place, here is my question. Is there a way to cleanup the ExpressionCache class so I don't have to pass in the generic type arguments? Something like this would be nice: `ExpressionCache.Compile(map)(source)`. I tried messing around with the type signature of the Dictionary's value, but didn't come up with anything.

Comment: Not really relevant to your question, but there is a mapping library called _AutoMapper_ available. Might save you from reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Yeah, I have used AutoMapper and other similar tools on projects where they fit. It wasn't a good fit here.

Comment: I would put the generic types on the `Compile` method, not on the class itself.

Comment: @JackA. I tried that. That's what the last sentence of my post was getting at. When I supply the generic types to the ```Compile``` method instead of the class, I can't figure out what to do with the dictionary's value signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ExpressionCache does not have to be a generic type, only Compile method has to be...

```
public static class ExpressionCache
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<(Type, Type), object> _mapCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<(Type, Type), object>();

    public static Func<TSource, TDest> Compile<TSource, TDest>(Expression<Func<TSource, TDest>> map)
    {
        object cachedFunc;

        ValueTuple<Type, Type> t = (typeof(TSource), typeof(TDest));

        if (!_mapCache.TryGetValue((typeof(TSource), typeof(TDest)), out cachedFunc))
        {
            cachedFunc = map.Compile();
            _mapCache[t] = cachedFunc;
        }

        return (Func<TSource, TDest>)cachedFunc;
    }
}
```

You can now write

```
ExpressionCache.Compile(map)(source);
```

because C# will infer types of the generic Method.